# Disable AMD module loading

Tags: webpack, swagger, babeljs

I'm using a swagger-generated api in a stack that uses webpack with babel-loader. webpack tries to load the files as AMD modules and fails.

```
ERROR in D:/project/src/javascripts/api/location/model/Location.js
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'ApiClient' in D:\project\src\javascripts\api\location\model
 @ D:/project/src/javascripts/api/location/model/Location.js 22:4-34
```

When I remove the amd-part in the swagger files (below) it works:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
 // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
 define(['superagent'], factory);
}
```

I know that webpack loader "imports" supports a parameter define->false to solve such issues. But I could not find a solution for bable-loader. 
Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Would the following help? https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/3336#issuecomment-232126946

Comment: doesn't work for me :(
ERROR in multi global
Module not found: Error: Cannot resolve module 'babel,imports' in D:\...\src\javascripts
 @ multi global

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I added another rule to my webpack config. I import my swagger-generated client as a separate package, so I only wanted the imports-loader to run through `node_modules`.

*Note that the code below uses webpack 2 syntax. You will need to tweak it if you're using an older version of webpack.*

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'babel-loader',
      exclude: /node_modules/,
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      use: 'imports-loader?define=>false',
      include: /node_modules/,
    },
  ],
}
```

I'm not sure what your situation is, but you might need to do something similar. The code generated by swagger may not need to run through babel.